# java.lang.StackOverflowError at line A a=new B()

Tags: java

at line A a=new B() i am getting error

```
abstract class A{

}
class B extends A{
    A a=new B();
}
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B ab=new B();
    System.out.println(ab.a);
}
}
```

I don't know why am i getting that error

Comment: Stack overflow is almost always due to "infinite" recursion.

Comment: (And StackOverflow is due to infinite ennui.)

Answer (score 6):

You are *recursively* creating instances of B.

```
class B extends A{
    A a=new B(); // will get called infinitely. So, you get StackOverFlowError
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind  now i understood the concept

Answer (score 3):

A StackOverflowError means that you have too many function calls to fit their data on the stack. Usually it's an indication that you have infinite recursion going on, as you do in this case.

When you are creating the object B in class Test, the class B is creating another object B, over and over.

```
class B extends A{
    A a=new B(); // problem here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you call `B`'s constructor inside of `B`'s declaration is a case of infinite recursion. There's no way for that to work.

You'd instead have to lazy-load the instance on request:

```
class B extends A {
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        if(a == null) {
            a = new B();
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

Obviously this code isn't thread-safe, but it'll at least get you started.

Answer (score 2):

```
class B extends A{
    A a=new B(); 
}
```

At line `A a=new B();` , again the default constructor of class `B` is invoked. This keeps happening, and the stack gets full due to frames of `B`'s constructor calls.

Answer (score 2):

In code

```
class B extends A{
    A a=new B();
}
```

you decided that each instance of `B` needs to have its own field which will hold other instance of `B`.

So each time you call `new B()`, another instance of `B` needs to be created, but this another instance needs to also have its own another instance of `B`, and so on.

You can visualize it this way

```
new B()
  |(requires)
  +-- A a = new B();
              |(requires)
              +-- A a = new B();
                          |(requires)
                          +-- A a = new B();
                                      |(requires)
                                      +-- ... and so on until stack will overflow.
```